# In back end (java spring boot) sorting, how to sort with Alias name using pageable? Without parent table as prefix

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate, pageable

I am using backend pagination and sorting with java spring boot `pageable`. While passing sort field as `usercount` (This gives count of `user_role_mapping`), Java triggering an error **column f.usercount does not exist** .
Actually `usercount` not a column it's an Alias name.

How to sort using **usercount** as Alies name without **f.** as prefix?

API URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/facility/list?pageNumber=0&pageSize=10&sortBy=usercount&sortType=asc
```

Default sortBy & sortType are **id** and **desc** respectively in controller layer.

Java Code give below:

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize, Sort.by(sortBy).descending());
if (sortType.equalsIgnoreCase("asc")) {
    pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize, Sort.by(sortBy).ascending());
}
Page<FacilityProjection> facilityList = facilityRepository.facilityListing(12,pageable);
```

Postgres sql Hibernate query for listing facility details along with user count based on role id, given below:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = " Select f.name as facilityname,f.id as facilityid,count(urm.id) as usercount 
 from facility f
 join user u on f.user_id=u.id 
 join user_role_mapping urm on u.id = urm.user_id 
 where urm.role_id=:roleId ")
Page<FacilityProjection> facilityListing(@Param("roleId") Long roleId,Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `usercount` is aggregation function result. To order by this field query have to contain `order by count(urm.id)` instead of `order by usercount`.

In this case I'd suggest you to resort page content using `Collections::sort`

```
boolean sortByUserCount = sortBy.equalsIgnoreCase("usercount");
boolean desc = sortType.equalsIgnoreCase("desc");

final Pageable pageable;

if (sortByUserCount) {
    pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize);
} else {
    if (desc) {
        pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize, Sort.by(sortBy).descending());
    } else {
        pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize, Sort.by(sortBy).ascending());
    }
}

Page<FacilityProjection> facilityList = facilityRepository.facilityListing(12, pageable);

if (sortByUserCount) {
    Comparator<FacilityProjection> comparator = Comparator.comparing(FacilityProjection::getUserCount);

    if(desc) {
        comparator = comparator.reversed(); 
    }
    Collections.sort(facilityList.getContent(), comparator);
}
```

Comment: If you use pagination I suspect that `pageSize` is not a very large number (<1000). 
So sorting would be very fast

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not possible.

Having said that, I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Facility.class)
public interface FacilityProjection {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    @Mapping("SIZE(users)")
    Long getUsercount();
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`FacilityProjection a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, FacilityProjection.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features so you can see this as a replacement for Spring Data Projections that supports more use cases!